# dynamic infowindow with dynamic markers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am writing because I have made ​​a script that takes the json data to create multiple dynamic marker, and it works!
Now I'm trying to add the InfoWindow to each marker, but does not work.
My code is:

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"locali_json.php"+urlz,
    success:function(data){ 
          var json = JSON.parse(data);
          for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
            point = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].latitudine,json[i].longitudine);
            contentString = json[i].id_locale;
            addMarkers(point,contentString);
          }
    }
})}


 function addMarkers(point,contentString) {  
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: map
 });
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: contentString
             });
 markers.push(marker); // markers is an array
 infos.push(infowindow);  //info is an array
 for(var j=0; j<markers.lenght; j++){
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infos[j].open(map,markers[j]);})

  }}
```

anyone have any suggestions? or see where error?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get javascript errors in the javascript console?

```
for(var j=0; j<markers.lenght; j++){
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               infos[j].open(map,markers[j]);})
 }
}
```

Should probably be:

```
for(var j=0; j<markers.length; j++){
 google.maps.event.addListener(markers[j], 'click', function() {
             infos[j].open(map,markers[j]);})
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, you can try it. Includes a customized info window.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head> 
    <style>
        #map-canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 400px;
            max-width: none;
        }
        .gm-style-iw {

            width: 350px !important;
            /*top: 0px !important;
            left: 0px !important;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.6);
            border: 1px solid rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6);
            border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;*/
        }

        #iw-container {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

            #iw-container .iw-title {
                font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
                font-size: 22px;
                font-weight: 400;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: #39ac73;
                color: white;
                margin: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
            }

            #iw-container .iw-content {
                font-size: 13px;
                line-height: 18px;
                font-weight: 400;
                margin-right: 1px;
                padding: 15px 5px 20px 15px;
                max-height: 200px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

        #map-canvas img {
            max-width: none !important;
        }
        .iw-subTitle {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 700;
            padding: 5px 0;
        } 
        .infoDiv {
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .iw-bottom-gradient {
            position: absolute;
            width: 326px;
            height: 25px;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 18px;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 1800px; height: 1500px">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var markers = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Markers);
             window.onload = function () {
                 var mapOptions = {
                     center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                     zoom: 8,
                     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 };  
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
                 for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                     var data = markers[i]
                     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

                     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         position: myLatlng,
                         map: map,
                         title: data.title,
                         description: data.description,
                         icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png",
                         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

                     }); 
                     // Add the circle for this city to the map.
                     var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                         strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
                         strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                         strokeWeight: 2,
                         fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                         fillOpacity: 0.35,
                         map: map,
                         center: myLatlng,
                         radius: 19999.45454,
                         position: myLatlng,
                         draggable: false
                     });
                     (function (marker, data) {
                         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                              infoWindow.setContent('<div id="iw-container">' +
                                 '<div class="iw-title">' + data.title + "</div>" + '<div class="iw-content">' 
                                 + "<p>" + data.description + "</p>"+'<img src="http://maps.marnoto.com/en/5wayscustomizeinfowindow/images/vistalegre.jpg" alt="Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre" height="115" width="83">'
                                 +'<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>');
                             //infoWindow.setContent(data.title);
                             //infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                             infoWindow.open(map, marker);

                         });

                     })(marker, data);
                 }
             }
        </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace Map.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            {
                string markers = "[";
                string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PTS"].ConnectionString;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ProjeIlani");
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            markers += "{";
                            markers += string.Format("'title': '{0}',", sdr["Adres"]);
                            markers += string.Format("'lat': '{0}',", sdr["Enlem"]);
                            markers += string.Format("'lng': '{0}',", sdr["Boylam"]);
                            markers += string.Format("'description': '{0}'", sdr["Aciklama"]); 
                            markers += "},";
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }

                markers += "];";
                ViewBag.Markers = markers;
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```